# Ionic View Google Login Popup works in Firebase 2, but not in Firebase 3 (works in browser)

Tags: android, authentication, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement Google authentication in my ionic app. I found this sample app on GitHub ([click here](https://github.com/davideast/firebase-ionic-login-sample)) which uses Google to login.

- When I serve it to the browser (using ionic serve --lab), the popup works. I am able to login in and access the data.
- When I upload it to ionic and open the app on iOS/Android emulator, it works.
- When I build it and emulate it on android, the popup does not work.

I tried to upgrade the app using Firebase's Migration guide ([click here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web)), but I was only able to get it working in the browser, not in ionic view or android emulator.

I also added Google sign in to a separate app, but I was only able to get it working in the browser.

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (response) {
  // Login successful
}, function(error) {
  // Login error
});
```

Any help will be great!

A side question, am I still able to use Firebase 2.x.x even though I am using the new Firebase console? I think firebase did give me an error once saying I was using new Firebase console so needed to use the latest libraries or something.

Answer (score 5):

Firebase auth 3.x for Ionic/Cordova on android and iOS currently does not support signInWithPopup. The Firebase team is working on supporting that. 
Check this thread for more on how to handle this situation: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/cordova$20facebook/firebase-talk/mC_MlLNCWnI/DqN_8AuCBQAJ

For now, you can use signInWithCredential as an alternative. There are cordova plugins for Google and Facebook which would help provide you with an OAuth access token that you can use to call signInWithCredential:

```
auth.signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(fbAccessToken));
```

One example of a plugin for facebook sign in: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook